# Download web server structure with empty files

Tags: wget, curl, mirroring

I want to make a mirror of a Web server, but downloading the actual files will take too long. So I thought of having just the directory and file structure, and when I need the actual contents of the file, I can download just that file.

I have tried

```
wget --spider URL
```

and in a short time it has created in my local disk the directory structure with no files. But I've checked all of wget's or curl's switches and there is nothing like what I need.

Can this be done with wget, curl or any other tool?